# Editing and Resetting Permissions for all folders, subfolders and files

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, command-line, permissions, bitnami

I've just started to learn Linux Command Line. The setup I am on is AWS Lightsail bitnami Wordpress. I work with wordpress primarily.

I'm still confused about file permissions in Linux. **Why do I have permissions denied when I sign in as the owner?**

Whenever I have to ftp, overwrite, edit files and folders, I have to change the permissions settings for each affected folders and files manually via SSH.

More often than not, at the end of the day, I lost track of which folders and files' permissions I have edited and need to reset to default. I find this a chore and I believe there is a better way.

I wonder if there are lines of command that can

1. give me full access to all directories, folders, subfolders and files at once?
2. change the permissions for directories, folders, subfolders and files at once?
3. reset the permissions of all edited files to default/original all at once?

To check the permission of the file

```
sudo stat TARGETFOLDER
```

To change the permission of the file

```
sudo chmod 777 TARGETFOLDER
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a Programming Q&A site. You might get a better response by posting this on: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks. I'm a beginner and probably didn't use the right vocabulary. I'm actually asking about the Linux command lines.. for instance, what command to execute to give me full access, change and reset permissions.. I searched and found lines that can work on individual files but I am hoping to look for command that can change all at once so that I don't have to do it individually folder by folder, subfolder by sub folder, file by file and more importantly able to reset the permissions back to default all at once too. and of course a secure method too

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the commands you are currently using? We can then suggest how to expand them to more files/folders.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks. Edited. the command I use is very basic for beginner.

Comment: [How to Recursively Change the File's Permissions in Linux | Linuxize](https://linuxize.com/post/chmod-recursive/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

We configure the permissions of the WordPress' files by setting `bitnami` as the user owner and `daemon` as group owner of the files. This configuration allows you edit the files using the bitnami user and the webserver can use the daemon group to do the same. However, if you make changes to the application using the web interface (install plugins or themes), those new files are owned by daemon:daemon (the Apache and PHP-FPM services use that user and group so they generate the files using those permissions configuration) and you won't be able to edit them unless you use the command line and `sudo`. In that case, you can run the following commands to be able to edit those files using the bitnami user

```
sudo chown -R /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo chmod 640 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php
```

You can learn more about this here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLGgVZHi3XQNn4x0DU7Qj1r_inej3xEUda&v=nKfle7O0vN8&feature=emb_title

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2, you can try chmod -R option.
3. i think it can not. you should restore it. maybe it help.

Comment: Thanks for does that mean I have to keep track of which files' permissions are changed and have to manually change them back again individually?